# Updated HTML code in editor does not appear in browser until computer restart

Tags: python, html, browser, server

My problem is that when I write HTML code in editor, and later save this code it does not appear updated in my browser. I have cleared all cache but nothing, only when I restart my computer that code is shown in browser.

I am using Visual Studio Code (I have the same issue with Brackets code editor).

I am starting the project with the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal example that has this issue? That way we can help reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pta8np On the left side is code in editor on the right side is inspected element in browser, that is mine issue, code from editor appears in browser only when i restart my PC, i tried to clear cache, no any errors in console, nothing works